# How do you derive a component's size using @Self() decorator?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, typescript2.2

I'm working on a mechanism for calculating and setting CSS Grid layouts.  Part of doing this requires my components being able to detect their own size in pixels.  So far I've come across the `@Self()` decorator, but now that I'm actually at the point of using it I can't figure out how to derive any information from it about the component.

I made a class called `GridFactory` that I'm using to extend my component classes which is making it extra confusing trying to figure out how to add the `super` call properly in the `constructor`.  So far my class looks like this.

```
export class GridFactory {
    ScreenCore   : ScrnCore = new ScrnCore();
    GridSettings : GridSpecs = new GridSpecs();

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) onResize(event){ this.checkScrn(); }

    constructor( @Self() public appSpecs: ElementRef ){
        this.checkScrn();
    }

    checkScrn( specs: appSpecs ){
        this.ScreenCore.Width   = specs.width;
        this.ScreenCore.Height  = specs.height;

        this.activteGrid( this.ScreenCore );
    }

    activteGrid( data: ScrnCore ){ this.GridSettings = gridManager( data.Width ); }
}
```

So far I'm only trying to call it on the `app.component` which I have set up like this

```
@Component({
  selector    : 'app',
  templateUrl : './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent extends GridFactory implements OnInit {
    MainFrame: SiteFrame;

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) onResize(event){ this.calcScreen(); }

    constructor(public appSpecs: ElementRef){
        super(appSpecs);
    }

    ngOnInit(){ this.calcScreen(); }

    calcScreen(){ this.MainFrame = uiMonitor(); }
}
```

as of right now I'm getting this error in regards to the `appScpecs` variable

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'appSpecs'.

I've been looking up everything I can think of to look up to find more info about this decorator but I just haven't found anything yet.  Can anyone help me figure this out?

**UPDATE**

I changed the function to this

```
checkScrn(){
    this.ScreenCore.Width   = this.appSpecs.nativeElement.width;
    this.ScreenCore.Height  = this.appSpecs.nativeElement.height;

    this.activteGrid( this.ScreenCore );
    console.log(this.appSpecs.nativeElement.width);
}
```

I also decided to make one component class with everything in it just to put it all in one place until I figure out how to get it working.  I'm not getting any errors but the results are turning up `null` on my screen and `undefined` in the console.

Comment: `checkScrn( specs: appSpecs )` uses `appSpecs` as a type, whereas `appSpecs` in your constructor is a property. Is this intentional?

Comment: to be honest I was just following this example as a starting point https://angular.io/api/core/Self.  I was trying to pass the `appSpecs` property into the `checkScrn()` function to retrieve the width and height of the component to do further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
checkScrn(){
    this.ScreenCore.Width   = this.appSpecs.width;
    this.ScreenCore.Height  = this.appSpecs.height;

    this.activteGrid( this.ScreenCore );
}
```

`appSpecs` is a property, not a type, so using it as a parameter type is incorrect. You should be able to access `this.appSpecs` in any function of the class anyway.

Comment: ok that made the error go away.  But now I'm getting errors telling me `width` and `height` aren't properties of `ElementRef`.

Comment: Well that deserves another question then :)

Comment: ok I just made it `this.appSpecs.natieElement.width;` and did the same for the height and the error went away... now I have another error which I think is unrelated.